# Notepad++: Keyboard Shortcut to Switch Views

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

I often use Notepad++ in a split-view like shown in the image below.  I am really lazy and hate lifting my hand to use my mouse to switch focus from the left view to the right view and vice-versa.

Is there a keyboard shortcut which does that? I'd like to be typing in the right view, and then press a keyboard shortcut so the focus is in the left view and I can begin typing there.

[image: image of notepad++ in splitview]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have different files open in different 'tabs' then you can press <kbd>F8</kbd> to switch the focus to the other tab. This is the same as clicking View > Focus on Another View or. It is also the same as clicking in another tab or on the tab name.

Answer (score 3):

You can also configure your own shortcut through `setting` -> `Shortcut Mapper`.

The name of the shortcut you were mentioning is `Focus on another view` (#140 in the shortcut list).

I prefer to use `Switch to previous`/`next document` (#228 & #229), it's more comfortable if you have more than 2 open documents.

The default setting is <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Tab</kbd> for the previous doc, and <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> for the next doc.

Comment: Current location is `Main menu` -> #166: `Focus on Another view`.  Annoyingly, only one shortcut can be set per command, and no commands to focus a specified view (i.e. `left`/`right`) are apparent.  Thus my attempt to set up the same spacial navigation behavior that I use for tmux is thwarted.  N++'s shortcut mapper is also way overdue for a search/filter.